# A sort of partition of real numbers

Tags: real-numbers

I'm looking for two injective functions $f, g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $f(x)+g(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $\operatorname{Im} f\cap\operatorname{Im} g=\emptyset$.

I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: $f(x)=e^x$ $g(x) = x-e^x$, $\text{Im} f = (0, \infty)$, $\text{Im} g = (-\infty, -1)$

Comment: @Mike $x-e^x$ is not injective.

Comment: @Amateur Ah, you're right. How obvious. Sorry.

Comment: I think $f(x) := e^x+2$ and $g(x) := -e^x-1$ work.

Comment: @Amateur OP wants $f(x)+g(x)=x$, not $f(x)+g(x)=1$. If it were the latter, that would work.

Comment: @Mike Okay, my bad, it is late here I think I should go to sleep :).

Comment: @Amateur As a fellow mistake maker, I agree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: look for something of the form 
$$\eqalign{f(x) &= \cases{h(x) & if $x \le 0$\cr
                h(x) + x & if $x > 0$\cr}\cr
g(x) &= \cases{x-h(x) & if $x \le 0$\cr
                - h(x) & if $x > 0$\cr}}$$

for suitable "small" $h$.

[image]

Comment: Eh...  I'm going to need a stronger hint.

Comment: What would be the requirements on $h$ for $f$ and $g$ to be increasing?